# flex broken spark image

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

On my air application, I try to load image like this:

```
var imAc:Image=new Image();
imAc.source=rootFile+value+"-V-"+label+".png";
```

Sometimes, image source doesn't exist.

In this case, broken icon appear but if this error appear I'd like to change image source

```
 imAc.source= null
```

With mx:Image ioError property exist but I don't find the same with spark image.
Do you know how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a spark image control, the ioError event can be used to trap the error and null out the value (or put up a placeholder image). If you need more granularity than that, or if you're in flex 3, you can use a [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e13.html).

Comment: Ok with is       imAc.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:*):void { imAc.source=null });
It works well . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any methods within the Spark Image component that allow you to check of its existence, but the File class does.

```
new File("your/file/path").exists
```

will return whether or not he file is present.

The result of this can then determine whether to set the `source` property to `null`.

Comment: Thanks. But as the file locate on remote server you explain doesn't works.